# Game logic of spawer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am student and I learn with Unity3D engine. I working on small 2D game for beginning.

I need help with some game logic. Specifically how to generate game object reasonably in 4 columns. In this game I spawn game object that falling down from top of the screen. I calculate 4 columns that cover screen. I spawn randomly game object in this 4 columns. But game play is not good. I need a advice how to do better.

My idea is spawn one or more game object in row and reasonably rotate columns. I already spawn object in row. But how to create logic for switch columns? Something like switch (now first columns, now third, now first and fourth etc.)

There is my spawn methods:

```
 // Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    // width of one colums
    widthColum = ScreenCalc.DivideScreenInColums(colums);

    ...
}

public void StartSpawn()
{
    spawn = StartCoroutine(Spawn());       
}

IEnumerator Spawn()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
    time = GameController.instance.time;
    while (true)
    {
          // Random select from prefabs
          GameObject geometryObject = spawnObjects[Random.Range(0, spawnObjects.Length)];
          // X is middle of random picked columns
          float x = ScreenCalc.GenerateColumPos(geometryObject, colums);  
          Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(x, transform.position.y, 0.0f);
          Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;

          // Random object in row, will be spawned in one column
          int rnd = Random.Range(1, 6);

          // Spawn random count game object in one row
          for (int i = 0; i < rnd; i++)
          {                  
              GameObject temp = Instantiate(geometryObject, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);

              // Get Sprite render
              SpriteRenderer sr = temp.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

              // Change color of game object
              sr.color = colors[Random.Range(0, colors.Length)];

              // Get script for falling down
              FallingDown fl = temp.GetComponent<FallingDown>();
              // Increase fall
              fl.fallSpeed += 0.1f;
              // Wait between spawns
              yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0.35f, 1.0f));
          }
          yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
}
```

I tried do more Spawn method, one for each column and random generate wait time. But my logic was bad, because too much object was generate or too low and collide one column each other.

Here is a picture of my idea.

[image: Screen divided to 4 columns, each columns is spawn position]

On the picture you can see screen divided to 4 columns, every column is spawn position. I need to help with game logic how to switch spawn of object randomly.

For example spawn 3 object in row in column one. Then spawn 1 object in column two. Then spawn 5 object in column two and at the same time 2 object in column four.

I do not know how to explain it better. I am sorry for my English.

Comment: I think a picture of what you are trying to accomplish would be helpful to add.

Comment: You're `// Increase fall` code doesn't actually do a whole lot. As it's setting the fall speed of *the newly spawened object* by 0.1 once, it's then never touched again because the next time this line is executed it's on a *new* object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to spawn in each column independent of other ones.
You can add 4 spawner script for 4 columns.
Set unique column position(x) on those 4 scripts.
Or you can Start 4 coroutines for 4 columns like:

```
public void StartSpawn()
{
    StartCoroutine(Spawn(columnPos1));
    StartCoroutine(Spawn(columnPos2));
    StartCoroutine(Spawn(columnPos3));
    StartCoroutine(Spawn(columnPos4));
}

IEnumerator Spawn(float columnPos)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
    time = GameController.instance.time;
    while (true)
    {
          // Random select from prefabs
          GameObject geometryObject = spawnObjects[Random.Range(0, spawnObjects.Length)];
          // X is middle of random picked columns
          float x = columnPos;
          Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(x, transform.position.y, 0.0f);
          Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;

          // Random object in row, will be spawned in one column
          int rnd = Random.Range(1, 6);

          // Spawn random count game object in one row
          for (int i = 0; i < rnd; i++)
          {                  
              GameObject temp = Instantiate(geometryObject, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);

              // Get Sprite render
              SpriteRenderer sr = temp.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

              // Change color of game object
              sr.color = colors[Random.Range(0, colors.Length)];

              // Get script for falling down
              FallingDown fl = temp.GetComponent<FallingDown>();
              // Increase fall
              fl.fallSpeed += 0.1f;
              // Wait between spawns
              yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0.35f, 1.0f));
          }
          yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this before, but I need to solve how to switch between this coroutine, like for algorithm in post below. For example:

Generate from right to left. So I must active first coroutine and step by step active and disable next columns for that effect.

Answer (score 1):

You probably asking for an algorithm that spawn gameobject in a way that your game look interesting, Maybe this pattern will help you (you can add more steps).

1. Generate from right to left
2. Generate from left to right
3. Repeat above two line for random time period
4. Now randomly generate in four position at random point
5. Now Go to Step 1 repeat

Comment: Thank you I looking algorithm like this. I am sorry I know it seems to be easy, but I think it about all time :) and I can only image difficulty solutions. So that why I asked. Thank you